# Github action - get the latest version of dependency and install it

Tags: npm, github-actions

My aim is to get the latest version of @my_package version and install it as part of the workflow.
I have the below code snippet:

```
  - name: Install my_package for push event
    env:
      LATEST_VER: ${{ npm show @my_package version }}      
    run: npm install @my_package@$LATEST_VER
```

I get this error:

```
Unrecognized named-value: 'npm'. Located at position 1 within expression: npm show @my_package version
```

Do you have any suggestions to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the version in a separate step and set the value as an output:

```yaml
- name: Determine latest version
  id: version
  run: |
    echo "latest=$(npm show @my_package version)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

- name: Install package
  env:
    latest: ${{ steps.version.outputs.latest }}
  run: |
    npm install @my_package@"$latest"
```

This is useful if you want to access the version elsewhere, too.

Or you can determine it in the same step:

```yaml
- name: Install package
  run: |
    npm install @my_package@"$(npm show @my_package version)"
```